# How to use marionettejs on a module based folder structure

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am coming from https://github.com/backbone-boilerplate/backbone-boilerplate backbone boilerplate. 
I have tried backbone generator marionette https://github.com/mrichard/generator-marionette
but the folder structure is not convenient at all. 
Is there a boilerplate for marionette with the module folder structure that bbb use ?

Answer (score 0):

Check Derick's BBCloneMail. That's the classic folder structure for Marionette.

https://github.com/marionettejs/bbclonemail

Answer (score 0):

I quite like this [Marionette Wires](https://github.com/thejameskyle/marionette-wires) starter application by thejameskyle. Seems more up to date than others (that bbclonemail now hasn't been updated for years unfortunately).